# addition between two bytes assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, addition, x86-16

I found an addition in a programming assembly language book between two bytes and I don't understand why the result is that.

The numbers in base2 are: a=10010011 and b=01110011. The addition a+b=100010110 but if we add

10010011+
  01110011
= 100000110

Maybe it's incorrectly written there but I have to know. Thank you. And if you know some links with assembly programming language 8086 I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer Python gives for your question:

```
thomas@debian-laptop:~$ python -c "print(bin(0b10010011 + 0b01110011))"
0b100000110
```

It is therefore correct to say that `10010011+ 01110011 = 100000110`

Answer (score 0):

If your book says **The addition a+b=100010110** then your book has clearly an error. The sum truly is what you've calculated (**1_0000_0110**).
Please note that if this addition were to be performed in 8 bit arithmetic then the result would be somewhat different (**0000_0110**).

Comment: Yes, I know.Because it happens an overflow and the bit 1 is deleted,isn't it? How are you from?